# custom class to change background in multiple VC's; Type "class" has no member "x"

Tags: ios, swift

I created a class so that I can change the background image in multiple VC's at the same time much more efficiently. However,I keep getting the following error:

```
Type 'background' has no member 'view'
```

This is my class:

```
class background{

static func image(){

    let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "bg_name.png")
    backgroundImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
    self.view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)
}
```

}

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are creating a new class called background and all properties of this class must be declared inside of the two curly braces but you haven't declared a property called "view". Therefore "background" does not have a member called view.

What you could do to try making it work is to write the code inside of a func inside the ViewController class.